# Borrado de caracterres en TextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, textbox

Estoy intentando configurar el TextBox para que cuando se presionen las teclas `ctrl + delete` el TextBox se limpie. 
Intenté algo como esto:

```
if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Control && 
    (int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Delete)
   {
       txtContrasena.Text = "";
   }
```

¿Alguno sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si usas el evento `KeyPress` podrias usar el `ModifierKeys`

[Procedimiento para determinar qué tecla modificadora se ha presionado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-determine-which-modifier-key-was-pressed)

Pero es mejor si usas el `KeyDown`

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) 
       e.Handled = true;
}
```

en este evento los argumentos son mas completos para detectar las teclas que se pulsan

[KeyEventArgs Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)